# Can't find rc.status during install of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, centos

I am trying to install Jenkins 1.504 on a CentOS 6.6 box.  The script to set up the jenkins service attempts to run /etc/rc.status but that file does not exist.  I installed from an RPM that was given to me (the box is a standalone machine.)  I understand that rc.status is typically associated with the SUSE distro.  Do I just have the wrong RPM, or is there a way I can get this set up on CentOS?

Comment: What was the filename of the rpm? What does `rpm -qi jenkins` (or whatever appropriate name) say?

Comment: jenkins-1.504-1.2.noarch.rpm

Comment: That certainly seems to the an OpenSUSE package. Try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions ?